# Ways to upload data from Azure Linux VM to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a Azure virtual machine ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

In the machine, I have some files which I want to upload in the Azure blob (storage). The directory in the VM where the files are stored are updated on daily basis, so in the azure blob, I need to transfer the files which comes newly to the source directory.

Can some one please suggest what are the available and best ways to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to upload the files which daily update to the Azure Storage blob?

Comment: @Charles Xu: Yes, daily I will have files in linux machine and that I want to upload in azure storage.

Comment: I am working on the approaches and soon will share the update.

Answer (score 1):

You could [mount Blob storage as a file system with blobfuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux) on Linux. Another option is to use the Azcopy tool, see the [Get started with AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) article to download AzCopy. Refer to [Transfer data with AzCopy and file storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bash script which will upload data to the azure storage account & schedule the script execution as per required time using a cron job. 
You can [refer this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest) for a copy to storage.

You can [refer this link](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/schedule-tasks-with-cron/) for a schedule execution on the script